# Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, $17x \equiv 9 \pmod{276}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations, chinese-remainder-theorem

I want to uses the Chinese Remainder Theorem to solve $17x \equiv 9 \pmod{276}$ by breaking it up into a system of three linear congruences,
$$17x \equiv 9 \pmod{3}$$
$$17x \equiv 9 \pmod{4}$$
$$17x \equiv 9 \pmod{23}$$
For that I reduced it to

$$x \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$$
$$x \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$$
$$17x \equiv 9 \pmod{23}$$

So for converting this In terms of chinese reminder Theorem , I calculate The solution Of last linear Congurence as

$$x \equiv 13 \pmod{23}$$

So Our System Of Linear Congurence is now :

$$x \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$$
$$x \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$$
$$x \equiv 13 \pmod{23}$$

And now I apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem on it such that

$$92b_1 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$$
$$69b_2 \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$$
$$12b_3 \equiv 1 \pmod{23}$$
So $b_1$ = 2 , $b_2$ = 1 , $b_3$ = 2

So simultaneous solution be

$$92\cdot2\cdot0 + 69\cdot1\cdot1 + 13\cdot2\cdot5 = 199$$

But it's wrong (@_@)༎ຶ‿༎ຶ . Can please Please Someone can Correct me.

Comment: $(1)$ the correct solution modulo $23$ is $10$. $(2)$ You missed the "17"  in "$x\equiv 9\mod 23$"

Comment: The final solution is $33$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem to solve the following linear congruence: $17x \equiv 9 \pmod{276}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1986076/using-the-chinese-remainder-theorem-to-solve-the-following-linear-congruence-1)

Comment: @Peter thanks peter , it's cleared now

Comment: @cineel no it's not . I solve my question completely in different way and do some mistakes in between which is already cleared by Peter.

Comment: I added an answer that shows how to find the errors in your CRT calculation. This will help you to better understand how the formula works.

Comment: "x≡9(mod23)

So for converting this In terms of chinese reminder Theorem , I calculate The solution Of last linear Congurence as

x≡13(mod23)"  Huh? But you *just* said that $x \equiv 9\pmod{23}$.

Comment: Yeah @fleablood , it's was typo by my side. Let me correct to it

Comment: Correct is $\bmod 23\!:\ x\equiv 10\,$ but you got $\,x\equiv 13\equiv -10,\,$ i.e. you got the negated solution, so maybe you flipped a sign somewhere. Since you don't show your work for that we can't debug it.

Comment: @BillDubuque yeah yeah i actually understand that part. That was error in my calculations. But i correct it in my notebook

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as Peter has said in the comments,
$x\equiv 10\pmod{23}$
the last equation is supposed to be:
$92*2*0 +69*1*1 + 12*2*10=309\equiv 33\pmod{276}$

Comment: There is more than one error, and they can be precisely located by a standard proof debugging method - see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Below I show how to easily find the errors. [Recall (read!)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3095229/242) that the reason the CRT formula works is because each summand has the sought value for one modulus, and is $\equiv 0\,$ for all others. Thus your last summand  $\,s = \color{#0a0}{13}\cdot 2\cdot\color{#c00} 5\,$ should satisfy $\,s\equiv 0  $ mod $3\ \&\ 4$, and have the sought value mod $23$, i.e. $\,s\,$ should be a root of  $\,17\:\! s\equiv 9\pmod{\!23}$.

But your $\,s\not\equiv 0  $ mod $3\ \&\ 4$. The CRT formula achieves that by including a $\rm\color{#0a0}{first\  factor}$ of $\,3\cdot 4 = 12$, but your first factor is $\color{#0a0}{13}$. Fixing that typo your summand becomes $\,s = 12\cdot 2\cdot\color{#c00} 5$.

Finally $\,s\,$ must be a root of $17s\equiv 9\pmod{23}\,$ but yours has  $17s\equiv 15\not\equiv 9$. The CRT formula achieves that by choosing a root $\,r\,$ then writing $\,s = 12\:\!(12^{-1}\bmod 23)\:\!r\equiv r.\,$ Your 2nd factor $\,12^{-1}\equiv 2\,$ is correct but your $\rm\color{#c00}{3rd\  factor}$ $\,r\equiv \color{#c00}5\,$ is not a root since $17\cdot 5\equiv 17\not\equiv 9$. Let's fix that  by calculating a  root $\,r\,$ by [twiddling](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242) to exact quotients

$$\bmod 23\!:\,\ 17r\equiv 9\iff r\equiv \dfrac{9}{17}\equiv\dfrac{9}{-6}\equiv\dfrac{-3}{2}\equiv\dfrac{20}2\equiv 10\qquad\qquad$$

Thus the correct summand for modulus $\,23\,$ is $\,s = 12\cdot 2\cdot 10$.

Notice how a good understanding of the reason that the CRT formula works allowed us to easily troubleshoot the problem. This is true in general - if you understand the idea behind a proof or formula then you can debug an erroneous application of it be going through the proof line-by-line to determine the first place where the proof breaks down in your special case. For more examples of this debugging method see a "proof" [that $1 = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/152860/24) and a "proof" [that $2 = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/118006/242).

---

Below I explain from a general viewpoint the method used in sirous's answer.

$\begin{align}\  17x&\equiv 9\!\!\!\pmod{\!276}\\[.2em] 
\iff\qquad  \color{#c00}{17}x {-}\color{#0a0}{276}k &= 9,\ \, {\rm note}\ \,\color{#0a0}{276\equiv 4}\!\!\!\pmod{\!\color{#c00}{17}},\,\ \rm so\\[.2em]   
\iff\!\:\! \bmod \color{#c00}{17}\!:\ \ \ {-}\color{#0a0}4k&\equiv 9\equiv -8\iff \color{#c00}{k\equiv 2}\\[.3em]
\iff\:\! \qquad\qquad\quad\ \   x\, &=\, \dfrac{9\!+\!276\color{#c00}k}{17} = \dfrac{9\!+\!{276}(\color{#c00}{2\!+\!17j})}{17} \equiv 33\!\!\!\!\pmod{\!276}
\end{align}$

The above method may be viewed a bit more *conceptually* as computing  a value of $\,\color{#c00}k\,$ that makes *exact* the following quotient $\, x\equiv \dfrac{9}{17}\equiv \dfrac{9+276\color{#c00}k}{17}\pmod{\!276},\,$ cf. [inverse reciprocity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242).

Comment: Wow thanks. I am reading this. If I have to ask any question about it, I will definitely ask you.

Comment: @AMIT Did you understand it? If not I can elaborate if you tell me which points are not clear. It is worth the effort to understand it since it will give you a better grasp of CRT (often the motivation for the CRT formula - explained in the linked post - is not presented in textbooks).

Comment: @BillDubuque nah after seeing your reply in linked post and then read here , i totally understand this. Actually this makes my proof of CRT more clear also . Thanks

Comment: @Amit Great, glad it helped.

Answer (score -1):

$17x\equiv 9\bmod 276$

$276=16\times 17 +4\Rightarrow 17x=9+(16(17)+4)k$

$\Rightarrow 17(x-16k)=9+4k$

For $k=2$ we have:

$17(x-16\times2)=9+4\times 2=17$

$\Rightarrow x-32=1\rightarrow x=33$

$k=53\rightarrow x-53\times 16=13\times 17\rightarrow x=861$

K makes an arithmetic progression with common difference $d=51$:

$k= 2, 53, 104, 155\cdot\cdot\cdot$

Comment: @AMIT MITAL, my methode is much easier if we do not have to use Chinies remainder theorem.

Comment: yeah sirous , thanks a lot. It's really a easy way for solving it.  My motive wasn't to solve this question but learn myself the Chinese reminder Theorm and how can i use in more critical situation. But i learned to see this question in new way by your answer so thank you very much

Comment: @AmitMittal, You'r welcome

Comment: @Amit Essentially the answer solves $\, 17x -276k = 9\,$ by using the $\it extended\,$ Euclidean algorithm to compute $\,\gcd(17,276),\,$ a standard method - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242). The following comment presents it more explicitly in this form.

Comment: $$\begin{align}\  17x&\equiv 9\!\!\!\pmod{\!276}\\[.2em] 
\iff\qquad  \color{#c00}{17}x {-}\color{#0a0}{276}k &= 9,\ \, {\rm note}\ \,\color{#0a0}{276\equiv 4}\!\!\!\pmod{\!\color{#c00}{17}},\,\ \rm so\\[.2em]   
\iff\! \bmod \color{#c00}{17}\!:\ \ \ {-}\color{#0a0}4k&\equiv 9\equiv -8\iff \color{#c00}{k\equiv 2}\\[.3em]
\iff \qquad\qquad\quad\ \   x\, &=\, \dfrac{9\!+\!276\color{#c00}k}{17} = \dfrac{9\!+\!{276}(\color{#c00}{2\!+\!17j})}{17} \equiv 33\!\!\!\!\pmod{\!276}
\end{align}\qquad$$

Comment: @Amit $\  \ $ The proof given in the prior comment can be viewed more conceptually  as computing the value of $\,\color{#c00}k\,$ that makes *exact* the quotient $\, x =(9+276\color{#c00}k)/17.\,$ This leads to the [inverse reciprocity algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242).